# How to use HtmlService in Gmail add-on using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am creating a Gmail Add-on. The following reference page says - 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/reference/

"Gmail add-ons are built using Apps Script and the many services it provides. You can use any of the Apps Script services when building your add-on"

Basically, I want to have the small screen to pop up on clicking a button in my Gmail add-on.

As of now I have added a button in my section as follows and tied it to an action handler 'htmltest':-

```
var htmlTest = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('htmlTest');
var button = CardService.newTextButton().setText("htmlTest").setOnClickAction(htmlTest);
section.addWidget(button);
```

This is how htmlTest looks like:-

```
function htmlTest(e){
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('doubleCheck');
}
```

And this is the doubleCheck.html file I want it to pop up:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, World!
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I click the button it gives a run-time error:-
**Missing required fields in markup:**

Any clues how to use HtmlService while creating Gmail

Comment: I don't think HTMLService is available for Gmail add-ons.. We are required to use CardService instead.. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/

Please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: Its written here(https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/reference/) that "You can use any of the Apps Script services when building your add-on, but the following are often particularly useful: are cardService, PropertiesService etc..."

Comment: hmm... anyway, for what it's worth, CardService has a facility for popups as well... refer https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/reference/card-service/open-link

Comment: Cool. If that works, it would be helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google script use html service in gmail addon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48636518/11683)

Answer (score 2):

In the overview section of the CardService, It quotes:

“Currently you can only use this service to construct Gmail add-ons.“

So HtmlService is not available in constructing Gmail addon’s currently.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/

Comment: I think you mean "Workspace add-ons" as the text has changed I think

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR:

> To build interfaces for Gmail add-ons, you must use the Card service
>   instead [of the HTML Service].

Quoted from your [reference](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/reference/), under `HTML service`.

For popups, +1 to @akshay who recommended OVERLAY: `CardService.newOpenLink().setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.OVERLAY)`, which will "Open as an overlay such as a pop-up". See [CardService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/) [OpenAs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/open-as).