# google script use html service in gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I've try to create simple form in gmail addon,

how to use html [service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/)

The below code,i have tried,

```
function buildAddOn(e) {
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
  var test_card = doGet()
  cards.push(test_card);
  return cards;
}
function doGet() {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use HtmlService in Gmail add-on using App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477246/how-to-use-htmlservice-in-gmail-add-on-using-app-script)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understood that you want to use HTML at Gmail add-on. If my understanding is correct, how about these sample scripts?

#### Sample script 1 :

```
function buildAddOn() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplate('<b>Hello, world!</b>').evaluate().getContent();
  return CardService.newCardBuilder()
  .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('sample'))
  .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue().setContent(html)))
  .build();
}
```

#### Sample script 2 :

Code.gs

```
function buildAddOn() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate().getContent();
  return CardService.newCardBuilder()
  .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('sample'))
  .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue().setContent(html)))
  .build();
}
```

index.html

```
<b>Hello, world!</b>
```

#### Result :

[image]

#### Note :

- As a sample, Manifests was used from [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/quickstart#step_2_update_the_script_manifest).
- This is a very simple script. So please modify it for your environment.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi its possible create forms in gmail addon by using html servcies

Comment: @Robert I have never tried it for gmail add-on. So I'm not sure whether the custom forms can be created. But it's worth a try.

Comment: I spent quite some time on this, and confirm that it's not possible. Please see the official documentation here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions  (You can't design a custom UI for your add-on using HTML, CSS and Javascript.)