# Using CardService with HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons, gsuite-addons

Google Add-Ons has pivoted towards using CardService widgets. I am trying to create a drop-down menu but the ListBox class is deprecated. The docs forwarded me to HTML services but there's no documentation anywhere about how to use them in the context of CardServices. Here is my code:

**GetContextualAddOn.gs**

```
function createReply(e) {
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
    GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

  var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
    var draft = message.createDraftReply("Got your message");

    return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
        .setGmailDraft(draft).build();
}



function getContextualAddOn() {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Respond to Email'));
  var section = CardService.newCardSection();
  var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('createReply');

  function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dropdown');
  }

  section.addWidget(CardService
                    .newTextButton()
                    .setText('Respond')
                    .setComposeAction(action, CardService.ComposedEmailType.REPLY_AS_DRAFT));

  card.addSection(section);

  return [card.build()];
}
```

the doGet() method shown above is trying to access a dropdown.html file that I created:

```
**dropdown.html**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>test</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**How would I integrate the HTML into my current card.build? Should I be approaching it differently, and if so, can someone provide a code sample?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use HtmlService in Gmail add-on using App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477246/how-to-use-htmlservice-in-gmail-add-on-using-app-script)

Answer (score 2):

The CardService service can only be used with Google Workspace add-ons. They are not available in Google Docs add-ons or web apps built with Apps Script.

Comment: Is this still valid?

Comment: @JobinJoseph Yes

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can't yet use a custom HTML in Gmail Add-ons yet. You can though use them in Google Docs/Sheets Add-on using HTML Service.

In Gmail Add-ons you can use the correct Selection Input in the Card Service to create a Dropdown field.
Official Doc Here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input

Use the Selection Input Type as **CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN**

Here is a code sample to get you started:

```
var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Dropdown Sample Card'));
var dropdownSection = CardService.newCardSection();
var dropdown = CardService.newSelectionInput()
   .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
   .setTitle("A Dropdown. Only a single selection is allowed.")
   .setFieldName("dropdown_field")
   .addItem("option one title", "option_one_value", true)
   .addItem("option  two title", "option_two_value", false)
   .addItem("option  three title", "option_three_value", false);

dropdownSection.addWidget(dropdown);
card.addSection(dropdownSection);
return [card.build()];
```

Comment: Custom HTML won't happen in Gmail add-ons, by their design.

Comment: Yes, they specify in their official doc that "Currently you can only use this service to construct Gmail add-ons." https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/